# Generate an array in C# at the desired length, each element has desired initial value

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Just like in Python we can generate an array of length 5 where each element is 0xF by:

```
my_array = [0xF for i in range(5)]
```

From this I get my array:
    [0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF, 0xF]

Is there any equivalent way in C# to generate an array with given length and initial value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

`var myArray = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(x => 15).ToArray();`

Comment: Or `Enumerable.Repeat(15, 5).ToArray()`

Comment: Wow. Haven't known before that [Enumurable] can do range, repeat function. Thanks a lot!